# Getting end of period change with different index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, panel

I’ve got a Panel of DataFrames containing yahoo finance stocks. 
I want to re-index the stocks by Date inside the Panel:

To be more specific: 
What I mean in simple words is to get the difference from the beginning of the Q1 2013 for e.g. stock quote ‘AA’ from the end of the Quarter.

The expected result from:
AA[‘Close’][‘March28,2013’] - AA[‘Open’][‘January2,2013’]
is 8.52(march closing price)- 8.99(January closing price) = -0.47(difference).

I want to do this for all the Quarters that I have in single day data from Q1 2010 until Q3 2013 to get the difference. That is to change the index from daily to quarter.
What is the best way to do it?

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post what you expect your solution to look like so that I know I'm answering the correct question.  I don't think the way I've interpreted your question makes sense.  Edit your question to clarify and I'll edit my answer accordingly.

When you're working with Time Series data, there are some special `resampling` methods that are handy in cases like this.
Conceptually they're similar to `groupby` operations.

First of all, fetch the data:

```
pan = DataReader(['AAPL', 'GM'], data_source='yahoo')
```

For demonstration, focus on just AAPL.

```
df = pan.xs('AAPL', axis='minor')

In [24]: df.head()
Out[24]: 
              Open    High     Low   Close    Volume  Adj Close
Date                                                           
2010-01-04  213.43  214.50  212.38  214.01  17633200     209.51
2010-01-05  214.60  215.59  213.25  214.38  21496600     209.87
2010-01-06  214.38  215.23  210.75  210.97  19720000     206.53
2010-01-07  211.75  212.00  209.05  210.58  17040400     206.15
2010-01-08  210.30  212.00  209.06  211.98  15986100     207.52
```

Now use the `resample` method to get to the frequency you're looking for: I'm going to demonstart quarterly, but you can substitue the appropriate [code](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).  We'll use `BQS` for *B*usiness *Q*uarterly *S*tart of quarter.  To aggregate, we take the sum.

```
In [33]: df.resample('BQS', how='sum').head()
Out[33]: 
                Open      High       Low     Close      Volume  Adj Close
Date                                                                     
2010-01-01  12866.86  12989.62  12720.40  12862.16  1360687400   12591.73
2010-04-01  16083.11  16255.98  15791.50  16048.55  1682179900   15711.11
2010-07-01  16630.16  16801.60  16437.74  16633.93  1325312300   16284.18
2010-10-01  19929.19  20069.74  19775.96  19935.66  1025567800   19516.49
2011-01-03  21413.54  21584.60  21219.88  21432.36  1122998000   20981.76
```

Ok so now we want the `Open` for today minus the `Close` for yesterday for the gross change.  Or `(today / yesterday) - 1` for the percentage change.  To do this, use the `shift` method, which shifts all the data down one row.

```
In [34]: df.resample('BQS', how='sum')['Open'] - df.resample('BQS', how='sum').shift()['Close']
Out[34]: 
Date
2010-01-01         NaN
2010-04-01     3220.95
2010-07-01      581.61
2010-10-01     3295.26
2011-01-03     1477.88
2011-04-01     -119.37
2011-07-01     3058.69
2011-10-03      338.77
2012-01-02     6487.65
2012-04-02     5479.15
2012-07-02     3698.52
2012-10-01    -4367.70
2013-01-01    -7767.81
2013-04-01     -355.53
2013-07-01   -19491.64
Freq: BQS-JAN, dtype: float64
```

You could write a function and `apply` it to each DataFrame in the panel you get from Yahoo.